# How to Create Curved Level Boundaries with Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, game-physics

[image: Map]

I want a boundary like in the image above. Imagine the black as physics enabled wall and the red dot as the hero. The hero must move inside the boundaries.

```
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
```

Only creates straight lines.

Is it possible in iOS7 or iOS8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want [`bodyWithEdgeLoopFromPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithEdgeLoopFromPath%3a), which you pass a `CGPathRef`. You [can get that](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIBezierPath/CGPath) from a `UIBezierPath`. Something like this:

```
UIBezierPath *path = [...]; //Create path to your specifications
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromPath:path.CGPath];
```

The only requirement is that the path can't intersect itself.